# Excluding points within list of buildings' shapes in Python

Tags: python, folium, shapely, osmnx

I have a dataframe that contains thousands of points with geolocation (longitude, latitude) for Washington D.C. The following is a snippet of it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [ 38.897221,38.888100,38.915390,38.895100,38.895100,38.901005,38.960491,38.996342,38.915310,38.936820], 'lng': [-77.031048,-76.898480,-77.021380,-77.036700,-77.036700   ,-76.990784,-76.862907,-77.028131,-77.010403,-77.184930]})
```

If you plot the points in the map you can see that some of them are clearly within some buildings:

```
import folium
wash_map = folium.Map(location=[38.8977, -77.0365], zoom_start=10)
for  index,location_info in df.iterrows():
      folium.CircleMarker(
          location=[location_info["lat"], location_info["lng"]], radius=5,
          fill=True, fill_color='red',).add_to(wash_map)
wash_map.save('example_stack.html')
import webbrowser
import os
webbrowser.open('file://'+os.path.realpath('example_stack.html'), new=2)
```

My goal is to exclude all the points that are within buildings. For that, I first download bounding boxes for the city buildings and then try to exclude points within those polygons as follows:

```
import osmnx as ox
#brew install spatialindex this solves problems in mac
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_console=True)
ox.__version__
tags = {"building": True}
gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point([38.8977, -77.0365], tags, dist=1000)
gdf.shape
```

For computational simplicity I have requested the shapes of all buildings around the White house with a radius of 1 km. On my own code I have tried with bigger radiuses to make sure all the buildings are included.

In order to exclude points within the polygons I developed the following function (which includes the shape obtention):

```
def buildings(df,center_point,dist):
    import osmnx as ox
    #brew install spatialindex this solves problems in mac
    %matplotlib inline
    ox.config(log_console=True)
    ox.__version__
    tags = {"building": True}
    gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point(center_point, tags,dist)
    from shapely.geometry import Point,Polygon
    # Next step is to put our coordinates in the correct shapely format: remember to run the map funciton before
    #df['within_building']=[]
    for point in range(len(df)):
        if gdf.geometry.contains(Point(df.lat[point],df.lng[point])).all()==False:
            df['within_building']=False
        else :
            df['within_building']=True



buildings(df,[38.8977, -77.0365],1000)
df['within_building'].all()==False
```

The function always returns that points are outside building shapes although you can clearly see in the map that some of them are within. I don't know how to plot the shapes over my map so I am not sure if my polygons are correct but for the coordinates they appear to be so. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert in geopandas, but I was curious about folium, so I ran your code. `for point in range(len(df)):` point is an index, so it looks like it contains all the data for gdf.geometry to match. Isn't it necessary to determine if each line of gdf is included or not? If this is completely misguided, please ignore it.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the comment. That part of the loop is intended to check whether a point `Point(df.lat[point],df.lng[point])`is contained in any of the buildngs' polygons. So for every iteration `gdf.geometry.contains(Point(df.lat[point],df.lng[point]))` returns a list with logical operators of length `len(gdf)`. I think one can also do it the other way around and check if a list of points is in a building and iterate over building shapes, not sure how to do it, though!

Comment: I am not a native speaker, so I apologize for the confusing content. I used the `tmp_gdf = gdf.geometry.contains(Point(df.lat[point],df.lng[point]));print(len(tmp.index))` in a loop process to get the number of The results are all 1160 cases. This is all the cases in the gdf. Please check it, I don't understand the function of `gdf.geometry.contains`, so I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Yeah! So my current problem is that all the results are `False` so it means none of my points is inside a building geometry but you can see in the folium map that it is not true. I am not sure where the problem can possibly come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example points you provided don't seem to fall within those buildings' footprints. I don't know what your points' coordinate reference system is, so I guessed EPSG4326. But to answer your question, here's how you would exclude them, resulting in `gdf_points_not_in_bldgs`:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd

# the coordinates you provided
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': [38.897221,38.888100,38.915390,38.895100,38.895100,38.901005,38.960491,38.996342,38.915310,38.936820],
                   'lng': [-77.031048,-76.898480,-77.021380,-77.036700,-77.036700   ,-76.990784,-76.862907,-77.028131,-77.010403,-77.184930]})

# create GeoDataFrame of point geometries
geom = gpd.points_from_xy(df['lng'], df['lat'])
gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geom, crs='epsg:4326')

# get building footprints
tags = {"building": True}
gdf_bldgs = ox.geometries_from_point([38.8977, -77.0365], tags, dist=1000)
gdf_bldgs.shape

# get all points that are not within a building footprint
mask = gdf_points.within(gdf_bldgs.unary_union)
gdf_points_not_in_bldgs = gdf_points[~mask]
print(gdf_points_not_in_bldgs.shape)  # (10, 1)

# plot buildings and points
ax = gdf_bldgs.plot()
ax = gdf_points.plot(ax=ax, c='r')
plt.show()

# zoom in to see better
ax = gdf_bldgs.plot()
ax = gdf_points.plot(ax=ax, c='r')
ax.set_xlim(-77.04, -77.03)
ax.set_ylim(38.89, 38.90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot! This works nicely. It takes a lot of time to finish the unions with big datasets (i.e. buildings 5 km from the centre  and 6000 points to check) though but I guess that is normal when operating when polygons.